# Texture clearing for no apparent reason

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a simple pixelart "game engine"/"framework" that uses a back buffer for rendering.

Somewhere the back buffer clears, but i don't know where.

Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 84
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 48

#define BLACK 0x43, 0x52, 0x3d
#define WHITE 0xc7, 0xf0, 0xd8

//scales backbuffer to window, also updates screen
void scaleScreen(int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* backbuffer);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //init SDL2
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0){
        printf("SDL2 init failed due to %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    //create window and renderer
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    window=SDL_CreateWindow("Game WIP", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH*10, SCREEN_HEIGHT*10, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    renderer=SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_RendererInfo info;
    SDL_GetRendererInfo(renderer, &info);

    //create a back buffer
    SDL_Texture *backbuffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, info.texture_formats[0], SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    //variables for screen size
    int curScreenWidth;
    int curScreenHeight;

    //getting initial screen size
    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &curScreenWidth, &curScreenHeight);

    SDL_Event event;

    //change render target to backbuffer
    if(SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, backbuffer)!=0) printf("Render target change to backbuffer failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());

    //fill backbuffer with "black"
    if(SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, BLACK, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE)!=0) printf("Render clear color change failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
    if(SDL_RenderClear(renderer)!=0) printf("Render clear failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());

    scaleScreen(curScreenWidth,curScreenHeight,renderer,backbuffer);
    
    //main game loop
    while(1){
        
        //getting window size
        SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &curScreenWidth, &curScreenHeight);

        scaleScreen(curScreenWidth,curScreenHeight,renderer,backbuffer);

        //check if quit
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){ 
                SDL_Quit();
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


void scaleScreen(int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* backbuffer){

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    if(SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL)!=0) printf("Render target change to window failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());

    //size modifier, basically width of pixel
    int sizem;

    //getting correct sizem, checking if sizem should be based on width or height
    if(width/SCREEN_WIDTH<height/SCREEN_HEIGHT){
        sizem=width/SCREEN_WIDTH;
    }else{
        sizem=height/SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    }

    //making a rectangle for sizing backbuffer on window
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.w=SCREEN_WIDTH*sizem;
    rect.h=SCREEN_HEIGHT*sizem;
    rect.x=(width-rect.w)/2; 
    rect.y=(height-rect.h)/2;

    //clear window. The error might be here, but i read the docs and I believe that RenderClear only clears current render target. Correct me if I'm wrong!
    if(SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0,0,0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE)!=0) printf("Render clear color change failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
    if(SDL_RenderClear(renderer)!=0) printf("Render clear failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());

    //copy backbuffer to window
    if(SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, backbuffer, NULL, &rect)!=0) printf("Texture copy failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    if(SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, backbuffer)!=0) printf("Render target change to backbuffer failed due to %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
}
```

As the long comment says, the error might be in the RenderClear function, but as I said i believe it only clears the current render target, but I might be wrong!

It works as I intended if I fill with "black" (the defined one, not full black) in the game loop, but I really think that's unnecessary.